# INVALID_ARGUMENT: cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I wanna store more than 500 docs in `firestore` based on clients requirement. I faced the same issue while writing(setting) documents to the firebase. After a lot of research in net i created my own solution.

Hope this helps u..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is for creating 5000 dummy records.

```
const trailContacts = () => {
  let names = [];
  for (let index = 1; index < 5002; index++) {
    names.push({
      name: 'trail',
    });
  }
  return names
};
```

and this is the code for storing names to `firebase-firestore`.

```
let contacts = trailContacts();
let count = Math.ceil(contacts.length/500);
for (let index =0;  index < count; index++) {
  let splicedContacts = contacts.splice(0, 499);
  let contactsBatch = db.batch();
  splicedContacts.forEach((con) => {
    let collection = {};
    let name = con.name;
    let collectionRef = db.collection('trail');
    contactsBatch.set(collectionRef, collection);
  });
  await contactsBatch.commit();
}
```